# sass-lint restrict partial BEM rule

Tags: css, css-selectors, bem, sass-lint

Let's say I have a class: `myclass__button-create--success`.

I want to limit the usage of `-create` part in:

```
.myclass__button {
  &-create {
  }
}
```

As it's not a new block, element or modifier.
Allowed structures:

```
.myclass__button-create {
  &--success {
  }
}

.myclass {
  &__button-create {
  }
}

.myclass__button-create--success {
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this restriction using `sass-lint`?